# SSH to bluemix from bosh and capture metrics

Tags: ibm-cloud, cf-bosh, gorouter

Has anyone tried connecting to IBM bluemix using bosh-cli. I am seeing performance issues in my requests and was going through this [article](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/troubleshooting_slow_requests.html) on cloud foundry. I am planning to login to ssh to gorouter and monitor go-router CPU utilization.

Can someone recommend any way to capture the following metrics from Bluemix:

- CPU utilization
- Latency
- Requests per second

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by "connecting to IBM bluemix using bosh-cli"?

When you think about the public available IBM Cloud (formerly Bluemix) that's represented here https://console.bluemix.net/ it's not possible. The bosh cli is to maintain the platform, thus Cloudfoundry and potentially other deployments but not your apps.

If you have a private installation you might check the metrics that the system provides. Infos here https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/running/all_metrics.html

When you want to have metrics about your app I could think off your app is providing these metrics. Or you put something in place like the New Relic monitoring. The have a bunch of application performance monitoring (APM). Info here https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents

HP